# Как изменить ссылки средствами apache (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

У меня на компьютере проекты разбиты по папкам.

Назрела такая проблема, что в общем то в итоге все что сейчас разбито по папкам с большой вероятностью будет лежать в корне в итоговом месте, поэтому дописывать префикс к ссылкам в коде не очень удобно.

Интересует есть ли возможность дописывать необходимый префикс к ссылкам в теле документа средствами apache, дописывая это в .htaccess (благо его можно легко менять не меняя php код).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно разбить проекты, то лучше сконфигурировать виртуальные хосты. Например [вот так](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: и прописывать все в хост? так себе вариант.

Comment: кстати а можно ли автоподдомены организовать для localhost?

Comment: проблему с hosts файлом решил Acrylic DNS Proxy и wildcard для localhost, открытым остался вопрос автоподдоменов 0_о